# Convert ExpandoObject to abstract object using Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, expandoobject

Sample Class:

```
public abstract class SomeBase
{
    protected int _x = 100;
    public abstract int X { get; }
    protected int _y = 200;
    public abstract int Y { get; }
}

public class SomeBody : SomeBase
{
    public override int X { get { return _x + 10; } }

    public override int Y { get { return _y + 20; } }
    private int _z = 300;
    public int Z { get { return _z + 30; } }
}

public class SomeOne : SomeBase
{
    public override int X { get { return _x - 10; } }

    public override int Y { get { return _y - 20; } }
    private int _a = 300;
    public int A { get { return _a - 30; } }
}
```

Object to ExpandoObject Method:

```
public static ExpandoObject ToExpandoObject<T>(this T target)
{
    var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    jsonSerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(target, Formatting.Indented, jsonSerializerSettings);
    var expandoObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, new ExpandoObjectConverter());

    return expandoObject;
}
```

Convert ExpandoObject to abstract object:

```
//someBase
//X = 110, Y = 220, Z = 330
SomeBase someBase = new SomeBody();
//someOne
//X = 90, Y = 180, A = 270
dynamic someOne = new SomeOne().ToExpandoObject();

Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<SomeBase, SomeBase>();
});
//I want
//someBase
//X = 90, Y = 180, A = 270
Mapper.Map<ExpandoObject, SomeBase>(someOne, someBase);
```

But error occurs.

> Instances of abstract classes can not be created

How can we handle this problem?

AutoMapper version is 6.02

*Please consider using Google translator because English is immature.

**UPDATE:**

I know about abstract.

I just want to know if AutoMapper can do the following:

```
SomeBody someBody = new SomeBody();
//someBase
//X = 110, Y = 220, Z = 330
SomeBase someBase = someBody;
SomeOne someOne = new SomeOne();
//someBase
//X = 90, Y = 180, A = 270
someBase = someOne;
```

**UPDATE Again...**

TestClass

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
    public SomeBase SomeBase { get; set; }
}
```

My final goal is :

```
var testClass = new TestClass();
testClass.IntValue = 10;
testClass.SomeBase = new SomeBody();

dynamic expandoObject = testClass.ToExpandoObject();
expandoObject.SomeBase = new SomeOne().ToExpandoObject();

Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<TestClass, TestClass>();
});
///Mapping the expandoObject object that changed the property to the testClass object again
///My expectation is that the type of SomeBase Property in testClass is SomeOne.
Mapper.Map<ExpandoObject, TestClass>(expandoObject, testClass);
```

Thank you very much for helping me with insufficient English and insufficient explanation.

**My solution**

```
var testClass = new TestClass();
testClass.IntValue = 10;
testClass.SomeBase = new SomeBody();

dynamic expandoObject = testClass.ToExpandoObject();
expandoObject.SomeBase = new SomeOne().ToExpandoObject();

Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<ExpandoObject, SomeBase>().ConvertUsing(new SomeBaseConverter());
    cfg.CreateMap<FirstItem, FirstItem>();
});

Mapper.Map<ExpandoObject, TestClass>(expandoObject, testClass);

Debug.WriteLine(testClass.SomeBase.GetType().ToString());
///"Sample.Common.Models.SomeOne"
```

SomeBaseConverter:

```
public class SomeBaseConverter : ITypeConverter<object, SomeBase>
{
    public SomeBase Convert(dynamic source, SomeBase destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var dictionary = source as IDictionary<string, object>;

        if (dictionary.ContainsKey("Z"))
        {
            var someBody = new SomeBody();

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ExpandoObject, SomeBody>());
            config.CreateMapper().Map(source, someBody);

            destination = someBody;
        }
        else
        {
            var someOne = new SomeOne();

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ExpandoObject, SomeOne>());
            config.CreateMapper().Map(source, someOne);

            destination = someOne;
        }

        return destination;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mapping to an abstract class...the compiler is literally telling you the problem.  You can't create an instance of an abstract class.  Simply remove the abstract modifier from `SomeBase` and the error will disappear.

Comment: "Please consider using Google translator because English is immature."
We don't know your language. I'm guessing Korean, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

See the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx) re abstract classes.

The important part for you is:

> An abstract class cannot be instantiated.

You need to map to one of the derived classes, or remove the abstract modifier from the base class.

AutoMapper is great if you have statically-typed objects. It handles polymorphism very well:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SomeBase1, SomeBase2>()
    .Include<SomeBody1, SomeBody2>()
    .Include<SomeOne1, SomeOne2>();

Mapper.CreateMap<SomeBody1, SomeBody2>();
Mapper.CreateMap<SomeOne1, SomeOne2>();

// for a single object:

SomeBase1 source = GetDatum();
SomeBase2 = Mapper.Map<SomeBase1, SomeBase2>();

// for an IEnumerable:

IEnumerable<SomeBase1> source = GetData();
IEnumerable<SomeBase2> = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SomeBase1>, IEnumerable<SomeBase2>>(source);
```

But you're using ExpandoObject, so it's more difficult. If you can differentiate which class you need by the data in the ExpandoObject, you could try something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ExpandoObject, SomeBase>()
    .ConstructUsing((ExpandoObject input) => {
        if (input.X == 5)
        {
            return new SomeOne();
        }
        else
        {
            return new SomeBody();
        }
    });
```

and then the code you were using before `Mapper.Map<Expandoobject, SomeBase>(...)` will work. Otherwise, you could specifically tell it which type to map to: `Mapper.DynamicMap<SomeBody>(someOne);`

Comment: @KimJiho I don't understand what the update is asking. Can you not just do `SomeBase value = Mapper.Map<ExpandoObject, SomeOne>();` ? SomeOne is still derived from SomeBase, so there's nothing to stop you assigning it to a variable declared as SomeBase.

Comment: @KimJiho Although I still don't quite understand what you're asking, I've added to my answer in the hopes that it covers the situation you're asking about.

Comment: I've fixed the issue. Your feedback has been helpful. Thank you very much. @john